# Memory unallocated pointer variable works. How?

Tags: c

I have written this code & expected it to fail, since I don't allocate memory for the pointer variable. It didn't throw up any error, to my surprise. What is the reason?

And if I, just randomly, delete 2nd LOC, it throws up a segmentation fault. How to explain for this seemingly strange behavior?

```
uint16_t *c; 
uint8_t *d;
*c = 1;
printf("%x:%x",c,*c);
```

Comment: The behaviour is undefined. It "works" is a mere side effect of it. You should not rely on it nor should you write code like that.

Comment: It's not strange, it's undefined.

Comment: I get it, it's an undefined behavior. Thanks for the answers @usr, @/martin-james

Comment: `c` is not initialized but the memory where `c` is stored has some value that depends on what the program did before. For example a variable on the stack depends on what was written to the stack before (when calling functions). So you might end up with `c` sometimes by coincidence having a value that is a pointer to a memory location where you program can write to. But it might also just be an invalid pointer.

Comment: What do you mean by "still worked"? What exactly did it do and why do you consider that working? I can't imagine any behavior of this code that could reasonably be described by saying "it still worked".

Comment: @WernerHenze, thanks for that answer. Helped me understand better.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i meant "still worked" as "didn't throw up any error".

Comment: @Cuperto But you expected it to throw up an error, right? So not throwing up any error sounds like it didn't work. I'm kind of puzzled how you can describe any particular behavior of this code as "it still worked". You would have to mean worked the same as some other bit of code, but there is no other bit of code. Wouldn't you?

Comment: It can be meant that way too. Changed my question to avoid ambiguities. Thanks for the suggestion, anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it is UB. Your observation of the code "working" in the sense of not causing a segfault or similar is more or less random. Your allocation of another variable on the stack might change **where** your c pointer is allocated, and thereby it can have a different (random) place it points to. (Or, to put it differently, it's initial random value will or might be different).

Observable different behaviour of a program depending on where and what (independent) objects are allocated within a function are a dead give-away that there is something wrong with memory allocation in the function.